# How to move my Eclipse AVD

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, android-virtual-device

Hi I don't know why eclipse android AVD won't move , I even tried ALT+SPACE but the emulator windows still in the corner of my screen

Comment: Click on the titlebar and drag.

Comment: there is no titlebar (lol not that noob bro :p)
I think no solution

Comment: @WassimHajji: The solution from VolChuk was helpful. I was then able to see the titlebar. After that I could drag my window around. This issue has nothing to do with Eclipse btw. You may wish to remove the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Open C:\Users\User\.android\avd\YourDevice.avd\emulator-user.ini
Set window.y = 40
Save and launch YourDevice from AVD
Scale display to real size if You want.

Comment: Don't use absolut paths, especially not with hard coded usernames.

Answer (score 0):

Use Alt+Spacebar, select Move from the menu, and use the keyboard arrows to move it.

Answer (score 0):

Alt+spacebar and then arrow keys on keyboard helped me solve this issue.